# How to make a discord.py bot send a message through the console to a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

[discord.py - Send messages though console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464933/discord-py-send-messages-though-console) - This question is outdated so I'm going to try and re-ask as the solutions provided there do not work.

I want my discord bot to send a message to a specific channel through input in the console. My code is as follows:

```
channel_entry = 614001879831150605
msg_entry = 'test'

@client.event
async def send2():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_entry.get) 
    await channel.send(msg_entry)
```

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to register this as a `client.event` as you are not *reacting* to something that happens in Discord, that means the decorator is not needed.
2. I have to say I am quite confused why you are using `get` on an integer in `channel_entry.get`. Just use the integer by itself. This is probably the source of your error. Because you are not passing an integer to `client.get_channel` it returns a None object, because no channel has been found. [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

Working example:

```py
channel_entry = 614001879831150605
msg_entry = 'test'

async def send_channel_entry():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_entry) 
    await channel.send(msg_entry)
```

Also make sure you have the latest version of discord.py installed.